# Does raiding make me more threatening?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

I've garnered an extremely high threat score from my recent conquests. Am I safe to raid my neighbors while it decreases or will that increase my threat level also?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. The only ways to gain threat is by expanding (gaining counties) or having your vassals expanding. Raiding ironically doesn't raise your threat.